# no se adapta el background-image a la version para moviles

Tags: css, reactjs

Hola tengo un código en React en donde coloco una imagen de fondo, el problema esta que cuando coloco la aplicación en tamaño movil la imagen se acorta pero no se adapta en su totalidad.. aca la imagen del fondo en su resolucion alta:
[image: backgroud-full]

y aca la captura de la version movil:
[image: movil]

el problema es que no se adapta en su totalidad, el fondo no sale completo, aca el codigo:

```
function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Nav">
        <NavBar />
      </div>
      <div className="bg" >
    
      </div>
      <header className="App-header">

      </header>

    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

y aca el css en donde monto la imagen que creo es donde esta el problema pero no se como

```
colocarlo:


body, html {
  height: 100%;
  }

  .bg {

    background-image: url('assets/wall.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: center;

  }
```

si le quito el height no muestra la imagen he tratado muchas convinaciones y no he podido, si alguien tiene los conocimientos necesarios, de antemano bendciones...

Comment: El problema la tienes por la forma en la que defines el heigh, fuerzas a la imagen a mantener esa condición (100vh); el background es para una sección de la pagina o para la pagina completa ?

Comment: para una sección, que se ubique arriba pero que se vea toda la imagen....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia los estilos con Media Queries en CSS

`@media screen and (max-width: {{tamaño-especificio-en-px}} )`

Dentro de la Media querie cambias los estilos de la imagen, por ejemplo el tamaño que quieres que ocupe, en mi caso `background-size: contain;`

Espero que sirva, Saludos !

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bg {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638869231977-567c5b62352c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1140&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: unset;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .bg {
        background-position: top;
        background-size: contain;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias funciono perfecto....